# Problem with a property name of an object

Tags: actionscript-3, flex4

I have this function:

```
private function returnFees(row:Object,name:String):int
        {
            var fee:int;
            for each(var obj:Object in row)
            {   

                if(obj==name)
                {
                    //fee=obj as int;   
                }

            }
            return fee;
        }
```

I want to compare the name of properties to the 'name'. But in this code the 'obj' is giving me the values of properties not the name.

Any ideas? thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a `for each` you have to use but a simple `for`. `for each` will give you the values and `for` the property name :

```
private function returnFees(row:Object,name:String):int {
 var fee:int;

 for (var rowName:String in row) {
  if(rowName == name) {
      //fee=obj as int;   
  }
 }
 return fee;
}
```

Comment: oops, didn't see your answer until i posted mine... ;) deleting my answer!